# Remove cookie from $http header in angular

Tags: angularjs, cookies

We use token authentication and send the token in Authorization header for each request.

But we store the token in cookie because it is used for multiple subdomains.

Angular $http will send cookie in request automatically. So I have duplicated string in Authorization and Cookie in the request header.

Is there a way to remove cookie for all $http request?
(We use Restangular. So perhaps this is possible by configuring restuangular?)

Comment: Cookie used for authentication is usually http-only for security reasons. You can not read/write it in javascript.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17847283/cookie-header-in-phonegap-refused-to-set-unsafe-header-cookie

Answer (score 0):

```
var cookies = $cookies.getAll();
angular.forEach($cookies, function (v, k) {
    cookies.remove(k);
});
```

try like this.

Comment: We store token in $cookies so that all requests to subdomains can share the same token.